# Gtag - basic 'purchase' event not firing

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, gtag.js

I have the following event setup to fire whenever a user on my site makes a successful transaction:

```
window.gtag("event", "purchase", {
    id: new Date().getTime().toString(),
    value: 59.97, 
     currency: "USD",
});
```

I picked the event up straight from Googles enhanced ecommerce documentation:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measure_purchases

No idea why it's not picking up my recent sales?

Note: I have enabled enhanced ecommerce in my GA admin.

Comment: Have you configured Global site tag according to [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs)?

Comment: Yes I already have

Comment: Does the event fire when you debug it via Chrome dev tools? see also: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gtmga-debug/ilnpmccnfdjdjjikgkefkcegefikecdc?hl=en

Comment: Do you see the request sent in the network tab?

Comment: What error message do you get in the console?

Comment: Is window.gtag definded in the console?

Comment: You could try the chrome extension "dataslayer" to see if you see anything happening. Otherwise, you should post a little more code for us to help you.

Comment: Check if the `value` parameter of your purchase event is equal to the total of all the items.

Answer (score 1):

You payload doesn't look to be compliant with the example provided. Try changing `id` to `transaction_id` :

```json
gtag('event', 'purchase', {
  "transaction_id": "24.031608523954162",
  "affiliation": "Google online store",
  "value": 23.07,
  "currency": "USD",
  "tax": 1.24,
  "shipping": 0,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "P12345",
      "name": "Android Warhol T-Shirt",
      "list_name": "Search Results",
      "brand": "Google",
      "category": "Apparel/T-Shirts",
      "variant": "Black",
      "list_position": 1,
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": '2.0'
    },
    {
      "id": "P67890",
      "name": "Flame challenge TShirt",
      "list_name": "Search Results",
      "brand": "MyBrand",
      "category": "Apparel/T-Shirts",
      "variant": "Red",
      "list_position": 2,
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": '3.0'
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Changing `id` to `transaction_id` worked for me!